# jQuery ajaxForm plugin double file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, ajaxform, malsup-ajax-form

So I have searched all internet for answer but nothing...
The problem is that using ajaxForm malsup plugin it submits my files twice.

HTML:

```
<form id="gallery" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload-gallery.php" method="post">
<input name="images[]" type="file" multiple form="gallery" id="gallery-upload" accept=".jpg,.gif,.jpeg,.png"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" form="gallery" class="btn btn-white" />
```

JS:

```
var options = {
    clearForm: true,
    beforeSend: function() {

    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    },
    success: function(response) {
    },
    complete: function(response) {
    },
    error: function(){

    },
    target: $(".gallery-preview")
};
    $("#gallery").ajaxForm(options);
```

PHP:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

Response:

[image]

I even add this code to JS:

```
$('#gallery').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
```

but the result is the same. Whats wrong? Is the only way to take every second file in PHP?

Comment: Is requirement to use plugin?

Comment: @Janis how is your JS code executes?

Comment: No its not a requiremet. Are there some suggestions? And it executes in html file first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue. It looks like the forms plugin doesn't support the `form="gallery"` attribute. Each input element (not just `type="file"`) with the `form` attribute is being submitted twice, even if physically outside of the form.

Comment: You are freakin' genius. Thanks man, saved the day. That was because I had form in form, so that one form wount submit other form and so on. But I dealed with that and it works, thanks man again.